# Getting an error when trying to edit and add posts in laravel voyager

Tags: php, mysql, composer-php, laravel-8, voyager

Am using
laravel 8.40
voyager 1.4

I created a BREAD with my posts table in mysql local database, I could browse the columns of the table, view and delete some posts from the voyager admin.

But when I try to edit or add a new post, I get the error as shown in screenshots below

[the error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNlhS.png)

[posts form the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfOkV.png)

Comment: What is a "BREAD"? What's the error you are facing? And how is this related to Composer? Please share more details, and please avoid using images for stuff that could be shared in text form